# Compaq graphics card not working

Tags: graphics-card, compaq-laptop

My friend has an HP Compaq 610 laptop, that wasn't working he brought it to me to fix it and I discovered that the graphics card isn't working, we need a new graphics card.
I googled a bit and found [this question](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video/Can-Graphics-Card-of-Compaq-610-be-upgraded/td-p/314703).

> The Intel Graphics Media Accelerator, or GMA, is Intel's current line
>   of integrated graphics processors built into various motherboard
>   chipsets.
>
> This is an integrated video chipset.  It is soldered to the
>   mothberboard so it cannot be removed or upgraded.

The Compaq I'm trying to fix has similar graphics card, is there a way to solve it? would an external graphics card work? If yes, then would any external graphics card work? Is it expensive it? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no". It's built into the motherboard and the architecture of the laptop does not support external cards.

Source from HP's support forum: [is there external garphics cards for compaq 610](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware-Upgrades-Replacements/is-there-external-garphics-cards-for-compaq-610/td-p/2674359)

Is it worth it? The age of the laptop is also a factor as to weather it's worth replacing. By the time you buy a motherboard, you may be able to add a little more money to get a new laptop altogether.

Comment: should I tell him to throw it in the trash?

Comment: It could be sold for parts. Or turned in for recycling. Either way, remove the hard drive to backup and wipe the data before doing so.